# Is this a known issue in BIT.TRIP Beat?

Tags: steam, bit-trip-beat

I'm unsure if this is a shader issue with my video card, but my paddle is the exact same color as the majority of the background in Bit.Trip Beat. I had a similar issue with Bit.Trip Runner in which the obstacles I was supposed to jump weren't showing up. I was able to fix this by going into C:\Users[Name]\Local\Bit.Trip Runner and adding ForceFixedFunction = yes to the .cfg file. I tried this in Bit.Trip Beat to no avail.

Long story short. Is this supposed to happen? If not, how can I fix this?

[image]

That's my paddle sticking out of the top of the pink blob. As you can see, this can easily become an issue as it makes my paddle **impossible** to see when the pink blob grows.

Comment: No, this is not supposed to happen. Have you tried updating your video card drivers?

Comment: I have. They're up to date.

Comment: The pink blob is part of the background, as is the word HYPER.  They should be faded greys (iirc), not bright pink.

Comment: I've seen on the net that `ForceFixedFunction = yes` in Beat.cfg should work on BEAT, too.

Comment: @Powerlord I've already tried that. Initially, there was no Beat.cfg in the folder, so I made a text file, added ForceFixedFunction = Yes, and saved it as a .cfg, but it didn't work. Worked fine on Runner, but not Beat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after doing some looking around, I found the issue. When I initially (and secondarily?) installed the game, it was a corrupted install. The game opened fine, the sounds worked, but I had the above issue. I say secondarily because I decided to uninstall, and reinstall the game, but, lo-and-behold, there still was no .cfg file.

Long story short, after a third uninstall/reinstall, the .cfg file appeared as if by magic in my Steam folder. So, I was able to apply the ForceFixedFunction = Yes to the file, save, and play the game without further issue.